# Node Agenda Scheduler Mongo errno: 20, code: 'EMFILE'

Tags: node.js, mongodb, amazon-ec2, scheduler

I am running a node scheduler using agenda. It runs fine for around 30 minutes and then it starts displaying this error.

```
{ [Error: EMFILE, open 'log/scheduler.log'] errno: 20, code: 'EMFILE', path: 'log/scheduler.log' }
{ [Error: EMFILE, open 'log/scheduler.log'] errno: 20, code: 'EMFILE', path: 'log/scheduler.log' }
[Error: failed to connect to [localhost:27017]]
[Error: failed to connect to [localhost:27017]]
[Error: failed to connect to [localhost:27017]]
[Error: failed to connect to [localhost:27017]]
[Error: failed to connect to [localhost:27017]]
```

I am using node js with mongo db deployed on a EC2 instance.

The code I wrote is here:

```
https://github.com/kelvinblade/bluesky-scheduler2
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

EMFILE occurs when too many file descriptors are open as there is limitation in an os for the number of descriptors to be opened by a process. 
You can reset this restriction by editing this file 
/etc/sysctl.conf
or a more graceful approach is to use some module that would take care and have a connectionpool  to monitor over the opened file descriptors. 
You may try node-graceful-fs or filequeue
Git source :

```
 https://github.com/isaacs/node-graceful-fs

 https://github.com/treygriffith/filequeue.git
```

Install apppropriate node modules by

```
     npm install node-graceful-fs
       or
     npm install filequeue
```

and replace your fs from default to

```
  var fs = require('graceful-fs')
    or
  var fs = new FileQueue(100);
```

Personally i feel filequeue is better queuing system.

Comment: i commented out the writing to log part and i'm still getting [Error: connection closed] , i tried putting db.close(); but then the scheduler doesn't run at all

Comment: Hi shinon i have setup a local mongo in my system and ran your code. Its working fine with agendJobs collection being populated. Can you check whether your localmongo is up and live